# phpMyAdmin video not displaying

Tags: php, sql, html, phpmyadmin, mamp

### -Thanks for all the help folks. turns out it was indeed my own stupidity. Table column on local db was called 'url', on web-host it was 'urls'. Apologies for wasting everyone's time!

I'm trying to make a webpage display some videos, the paths to which are in a database.

The following piece of code works fine on the Localhost (I'm using MAMP) but when I upload it to the web-server, it displays the names of the videos OK but I get "No video with supported format and MIME type found." in Firefox. Chrome and Safari both stall while loading.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<video width=\"600\" height=\"350\" controls=\"controls\">";
echo "<source src='".$row['url'].".mp4' type='video/mp4'/>";
echo "<source src='".$row['url'].".theora.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";
echo "</video>";
echo "<br>" . $row['name'] ."<br/><br/>";
}
```

I guess it might be something obvious but I'm stumped.

Any help much appreciated.

thanks,
Robert.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Well, how does your source code look on both servers (local and public)? Also, how does your database look like?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm just learning and this is the way I was shown. Is it the ancient functions that are causing the problem?

Comment: No, but you'll save yourself much headache if you did it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify the video is in the database(name is one thing, is the file actually there?)? If using upload form, it is necessary to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.  I assume the videos are the format you are trying to request them as.

In your post you say  "but when I upload it to the web-server", so the problem IS with the upload then, not the displaying of the videos? You seem to be saying you have a problem with the upload, but your code is the code retrieving it from the database.

So is the problem with the upload, or the display firstly.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I think it might just be that I haven't used the correct path.
The video is on the server, in a folder called "public_html/my_site/videos"

I've tried listing the location as: "public_html/my_site/videos/video_name"
As well as:
"my_site/videos/video_name"

Comment: Also, the videos load fine if I hard code them into the page.

Comment: You might be already doing this, but try putting the videos in a folder on your server.  Then in the DB just hold the URL to the video, then use the path to the folder(which is in DB) as the source in the video tags.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Yes, that's how I am doing it.